# ERROR ITMS-90502 on tvOS target

Tags: xcode, tvos, application-loader

I got this error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90502: "Invalid Bundle. Apps that only contain the arm64 slice must also have 'arm64' in the list of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist."
```

Although I have this variable on info.plist file: [image: info.plist]

My build settings (always building all architectures): [image]

Any idea for solving could help. I'm really stuck here.

I'm using Xcode 7.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, third party libraries (using pod) didn't have this flag.

Adding that solved it.

Comment: If you're using CocoaPods then you can get a post_install hook that will add this for you in this issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4514#issuecomment-154948222

Comment: @orta would try that next time. the problem was that I didn't had any clue where to start because error wasn't fully understandable. Hope would help others.

Answer (score 0):

This config resolve my problem

[image]